# Windows Socket Programming: MFC CSocket vs Win32 socket

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winapi

I am trying to understand how these 2 types of socket implementations vary? Is the `CSocket` class from `MFC` library is a mere wrapper around the `WinSock/WinSock2 Win32 APIs` or there is something more than that meets the eyes.

Also which is recommended to be used in case of MFC applications and in case of non-MFC applications?

Comment: It's a wrapper. And using MFC for anything is not recommended.

Comment: CSocket is said to support only WinSock v1 and not v2. Does that make any diff? Also why is MFC not recommended anywhere?

Comment: "CSocket is said to support only WinSock v1 " - well, there is one reason for not using it.

Comment: I can't speak for Neil's reasons, but the portability constraints put it low on my personal "use It" meter. What do you intend to use it for? If it's just for networking, there are a number of alternatives. [Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) may be one of the denser options, but it's a hell of a useful toolkit.

Comment: Do not use a user-interface framework for implementing networking code.  I think the original MFC team might have gotten too ambitious wrapping every handle based API into a C++ class.  Go directly to WinSock.  Write your own C++ class wrappers as needed, but do feel free to use CSocket for inspiration.